# My Gunpowder/Creeper Farm on Minecraft isn't working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made a creeper farm in my survival world with the normal idea of trapdoors, carpet, a cat, etc. I know that the hopper system for picking up the drops will work, but no creepers will spawn in!

This is the tutorial I used if it helps any:

Originally I built it just like he had it (which was relatively low to the ground), and nothing would spawn. So I raised it to be 128 blocks off the ground, because of the 128 spawn radius (which was really scary to build in survival lol).

I added torches on top of the farm so they wouldn't spawn there, and made a little room about 50 blocks under it to camp, and got nothing. After this I tried camping 50 blocks above the farm, and still got nothing.
I built an antenna that went 20 blocks above the farm & 15 blocks out, still nothing.

**To get the obvious questions out of the way**, I am not on peaceful while I am camping. I am also the only player on my world. I am on windows 10 edition, I am not sure if that impacts anything. Also, it is definitely dark enough for mobs to spawn.
[image: It's a survival world, so to get good pictures I copied the world & put it in creative.]

[image: There is never this much light, I just broke part of the wall to get a picture of the inside]
[image: This is how tall it is]

Comment: Creepers are already easy enough to kill with a sword and a bow why would you need more gunpowder? I have more than I will ever use

Comment: On this world I basically just do projects on survival, and I don't go through caves off of peaceful very often because I didn't want to die and lose all my exp lol. (I recently made an exp farm so that is taken care of aha) I just wanted to make a resource for brewing & tnt purposes, so I started that as a new project. I have worked on it for so long though that I just really want it to work.

Comment: Bedrock (incl. Win10 Edition) has some weirdo mob spawning rules. I don't know the exact details but the rules are completely different than in Java.

Comment: Thank you, I will read into this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be far away from your farm for it to work.  Try going 100 to 200 blocks away from it for a bit and you should get some gunpowder in your chests.